# What's the difference between "You're so deserving of it" and "You deserve it"?

Tags: present-tense, present-continuous

What's the difference between "You're so deserving of it" and "You deserve it"? This is in the context of winning an award

Comment: Are you asking about the difference between "You're deserving of it" and "You deserve it", or about how "so" changes the meaning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are different ways to say the same thing.

The second statement is much more common.

The adjective *deserving* when applied to people seems to have a [formal](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/deserving) connotation. To me the first sentence also has a greater emphasis and sounds more affectionate.